# Error in db2 sql code: -601 sql state 38000

Tags: db2, schema

CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA('CSH', NULL, 'ERRORSCHEMA', 'ERRORTABLE')

I used this SQL statement to delete all table related to one schema, but it didn't worked with error.

Can I solve this problem?

[error was like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrRdK.jpg)

Comment: Did you look up the error code and the instructions on how to resolve it? Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERRORSCHEMA and ERRORSCHEMA already exist, so you can try this;

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA('CSH', NULL, 'ERRORSCHEMA1', 'ERRORSCHEMA1')
```